# ServiceProvider.GetService<Type> throw exception for every usage

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I'm new to the whole C# .Net environment and I'm trying to deploy a simple Console .NetCore 3 application to windows server 2012 R2 from MacOS 10.14
the problem is the application does work on macOS but after deployment on windows it doesn't work 
on the server here's the code

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging();
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
Console.ReadKey();
```

I've debugged the code multiple time and exception only get thrown when GetService method
is used like here

```
var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
```

The exception message is

> The type initializer for Microsoft.Extentions.DependecnyInjection.DependencyInjectionEventSource threw an exception

I've searched for solutions but didn't find any not even a close one.

**edit 1:**

here's more details about the error , hope it can helps

1. Exception Message:

   > The type initializer for
   >   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DependencyInjectionEventSource'
   >   threw an exception.

   2. StackTrace:

   > at
   >   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type
   >   serviceTyp e)    at
   >   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
   >   key, Func`2 valueFactory)    at
   >   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
   >   serviceType, ServiceP roviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   >   at
   >   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type
   >   serviceType)    at
   >   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
   >   serviceType)    at
   >   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider
   >   provider)
   >
   > at Inj.Program.Main(String[] args) in
   >   /Users/programmer/VSProjects/Inj/Inj/Program.cs:line 19

   3. InnerException:

   > System.ArgumentException: External component has thrown an exception. 
   >   at System.Globalization.CompareInfo.CompareString(ReadOnlySpan`1
   >   string1, ReadOnlySpan`1 string2, CompareOptions opti ons)    at
   >   System.Globalization.CompareInfo.Compare(String string1, String
   >   string2, CompareOptions options)    at
   >   System.Globalization.TextInfo.PopulateIsAsciiCasingSameAsInvariant()
   >   at System.Globalization.TextInfo.ChangeCaseCommon[TConversion](String
   >   source)    at System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToUpper(String str)    at
   >   System.String.ToUpperInvariant()    at
   >   System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.GetGuid(Type eventSourceType)
   >   at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource..ctor(EventSourceSettings
   >   settings, String[] traits)    at
   >   System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource..ctor(EventSourceSettings
   >   settings)    at
   >   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DependencyInjectionEventSource..ctor()
   >   at
   >   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DependencyInjectionEventSource..cctor()

Comment: Hi jimmy mac, what does the `InnerException` says?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: External component has thrown an exception               Thanks for your fast replay

Comment: Do you own the extension method `IServiceCollection.AddLogging`? (If so, can you share it?)

Comment: Do you to resolve `ILoggerFactory` in `ConfigureServices` method. Alternatively, you inject `ILoggerFactory` directly in `Configure` method

Comment: no I don't own any extension method. @IvanGarcíaTopete

Comment: I'm very sorry I'm new to C# and I didn't resolve a way to do so @user1672994

Comment: Please post the complete exception details (which means exception type, stack trace, and message) of the exception and *all* its inner exceptions.

Comment: How do you use `var loggerFactory` in your code?

Comment: Very sorry for late replay, i've update the question with all the necessary exception data @Steven

Comment: Sorry for late replay ,aside from the above code there's no any additional usage i'm just trying to find why Dependency injection run perfectly on MacOS but not on Windows even though i'm using the same run time version on both platforms @user1672994

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is related to running the app as dll what need to do is to publish the app as self contained executable for the targeted platform so in my case I've just published on Windows server 2012 R2 from MacOs 10.14 using the following commands (this commands will not publish to the server directly you need to move the resulted folder to the shared dir on your server)

> dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64

yet better

> dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true

after moving the folders I've run the .exe windows executable and now it works like charm